# reactStringReplace(), replace multiple strings with different anchor tags in a same paragraph(string) having additional <a>tags

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

Below paragraph(string) is my sample string, 
I need to replace "line1" with `<a href="www.w3schools.com">click here </a>` 
and "line2" with  `<a href="/"> click here </a>`

This is a line1 in a paragraph. line2 in a paragraph. line3 in a paragraph `<BR></BR>`
line4 in a paragraph`<a href="www.google.com">click here </a>` ends here.

I am using below code:

```
{text.map((i) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {reactStringReplace(i,"line2", (match, x) => (
                <a href="/" target='_blank'> click here</a>     

            ))}
        </div>
    );
}})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   text = text.map((el, index) => {
        if (typeof el === "string") {        
          return (
            <span key={el + index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: el }} />
          );
        } else {
          return el;
        } 
      });
```

I added above code and it works fine.